# Group by sum not working all orders

Tags: mysql

Group by sum  can be caluclated same order no. overall orders cannot be considered.

example table

```
order no  meterial name  consumption
 001       abc             1200 
 001       abc              800
 002       abc              750
```

Expected output

```
 meterial name       consumption
   abc                 2750
```

current output

```
material name    consumption
 abc             2000
 abc              750
```

Comment: If there is no query, there can be *no* output

Answer (score 3):

Probably because you have `order_no` in `GROUP BY` clause (along with `material_name`). If you want one row per `material` then just use `material_name` column only, in `GROUP BY`, e.g.:

```
SELECT material_name, SUM(consumption)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY material_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try if you are working with MySQL:

```
SELECT material_name, SUM(consumption) as consumption 
FROM table 
GROUP BY material_name;
```